# An issue about the member function qualified by volatile qualifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    A() = default;
    A(volatile const A&){}
    void show()const volatile {

    }
};
int main(){
   volatile A a;
   //A b = std::move(a);  // ill-formed
   std::move(a).show();  //OK
}
```

Consider the [example](https://godbolt.org/z/joTMn5), the results of the example are out of my understanding about some relevant rules.

For `A b = std::move(a);`, it's ill-formed, because it violates the following rule, that is:
[dcl.init.ref#5.2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#5.2)

> Otherwise, if the reference is an lvalue reference to a type that is not const-qualified or **is volatile-qualified**, the program is ill-formed.

That means, a lvalue reference to const volatile-qualified T cannot bind to any **rvalue** even though they're reference-compatible.  `A b = std::move(a);` obviously violates this rule, hence it's ill-formed.

However I don't know why compile `std::move(a).show();`without reporting wrong. According to this rule:

> For non-static member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is
>
> > “lvalue reference to cv X” for functions declared without a ref-qualifier or with the & ref-qualifier

The type of the implicit object parameter of member function `show` will be `volatile const A&` . In general, it definitely violates [dcl.init.ref#5.2]. If change the definition of member function `show` to:

```cpp
void show() volatile const& {

}
```

`std::move(a).show();` will be ill-formed. So  must be some magic in the following rule that make `std::move(a).show();` be compiled before changing `show`. The rule is:
[over.match.funcs#general-5](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-5)

> For non-static member functions declared without a ref-qualifier, an additional rule applies:
>
> > even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as **in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter**.

Honestly, I really don't know what does the wording "in all other respects" mean? And what does the  "the type of the implicit object parameter" refer to?  Does the "type" refer to `volatile const A&` or the referenced type `volatile const A`? The wording is very vague. Anyhow, **lvalue reference to const volatile T** cannot bind to any **rvalue** of type `T`.  So, how to interpret that?

As a contrast:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct B{
  void show(){}
};
int main(){
  volatile B b;
  std::move(b).show();  //ill-formed
}
```

the type of the implicit object parameter of `show` would be `B&`, According to [over.match.funcs#general-5], even though ignore `const-qualifier`, it's still ill-formed due to it discards the `volatile-qualifier`. From this example, it implies that, For this sentence "in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter", where the type should refer to **reference type** rather than the type the reference refers to. If the magic is this, it's still not sufficient to make `std::move(a).show();`  to be well-formed.

So, how to interpret these issues? I don't know how to use [over.match.funcs#general-5] to interpret these two examples.

Comment: Isn't A b = std::move(a) ill-formed just because you don't have a move constructor?  ie. A(volatile A&&); ?

Comment: @wreckgar23  `A(volatile A&&);` is an avaliable candiate function for rvalue of type `volatile A`, however I use `A(volatile const A&)` here is used to interpret rule [dcl.init.ref#5.2], that is, the parameter of type `volatile const A&` cannot bind to rvalue of type `volatitle A`.(the additional [over.match.funcs#general-5] rule does not apply to constructor).

Comment: `will be ill-formed` `is well-formed`  - what is the basis of these statements? You are testing that with a compiler and based on that you say something is {ill,well}-formed? Maybe say "it compiles" or "it doesn't compile" ("with compiler version .. options ... and shows errors ...")?

Comment: @KamilCuk Well, a good suggestion.  I have added the link of godbolt in my question.

Comment: Do you need an interpretation of the std wording, or the explanation on how the code should/does[n't] work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> struct A {
>     A() = default;
>     A(volatile const A &) {}
>     void show() const volatile {}
> };
>
> int main() {
>     volatile A a;
>     std::move(a).show(); // OK
> }
> ```

The implied object parameter for the member function `show()` is, as per [[over.match.funcs]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#4), `const volatile A&`, such that for the purpose of overload resolution, we may, as per [[over.match.funcs]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#5), consider the data member function as

```
void show(const volatile A&);
```

Now, with this in mind, let's first simplify the example, with the purpose of:

- Comparing why an rvalue reference of `A` seemingly may bind to an implied object parameter or type `const volatile A&` but not to say a function parameter of the same type when the parameter is for a regular free function.

Thus, consider the following simplified example:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    void show() const volatile {}
};

void g(const volatile A &) { }

int main() {
    volatile A a;
    
    g(std::move(a));      // (i) Error.
    std::move(a).show();  // (ii) OK.
}
```

The error message at (i), in GCC (10.1.0) is:

> **error:** cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type `const volatile A&` to an rvalue of type `std::remove_reference<volatile A&>::type`
> {aka `volatile A`}

which is expected (as you have noted yourself) as per [[dcl.init.ref]/5.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#5.2), which disallows rvalues to bind, in initialization, to `volatile` references, even if they are `const`-qualified.

Then why is (ii) accepted? Or, conversely, why does the restriction of [dcl.init.ref]/5.2 apparently not apply for the similar case of the implicit object parameter of a member function?

The answer lies in  
[[over.match.funcs
]/5.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#5.1), which contains an exception for member functions declared *without a ref-qualifier*:

> **[over.match.funcs
> ]/5** [...] For non-static member functions declared **without a ref-qualifier, an additional rule applies**:
>
> - **/5.1** even if the implicit object parameter is not const-qualified, an rvalue can be bound to the parameter as long as **in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter.**

[over.match.funcs ]/5.1 removes the prohibation of [dcl.init.ref]/5 regarding rvalues (rvalue binding), and the remaining criteria is applied to whether argument (rvalue ignored; `volatile A`) can be (*"in all other respects"*) converted to the implicit object parameter (`const volatile A&`). As the implicit object parameter, as shown above, in this case is always an lvalue reference, "in all other respects" here essentially means that the implicit object parameter is *reference-compatible* (as per [[dcl.init.ref]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init.ref#4)) with the (rvalue ignored) argument type.

```
// [over.match.funcs ]/5.1 special case: rvalue prohibition waived
   volatile A a;                // argument: a
   const volatile A& aref = a;  // ok, reference-compatible
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ implicit object parameter
```

Arguably [over.match.funcs]/5.1 could be clearer on that it applies both for the case where non-`const` qualification (usually) prohibits from-rvalue binding, *and* that `volatile`-cv-qualification (usually) prohibits from-rvalue binding.

---

We may finally query the compiler(s) whether this is actually the particular rule which it uses to allow (ii), by explicitly adding the `&`-ref-qualifier, a change that as per [[over.match.funcs]/4.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.funcs#4.1) will have no effect on the type of the implicit object parameter:

```
#include <memory>

struct A {
    void show() const volatile & {}
};

void g(const volatile A &) { }

int main() {
    volatile A a;
    
    g(std::move(a));      // (i) Error.
    std::move(a).show();  // (ii') Error.
}
```

As expected, if we add a `&`-qualifier to the `show()` overload, (ii) likewise fails as (i) did, albeit with another error message (GCC):

> **error:** passing `std::remove_reference<volatile A&>::type` {aka `volatile A`} as `this` argument discards qualifiers

For this error, Clang (10.0.0) arguably has a more on-spot error message:

> **error:** `this` argument to member function `show` is an rvalue, but function has non-const lvalue ref-qualifier

Comment: I know [over.match.funcs ]/5.1 is a special rule that permits that code be compiled, as I have mentioned in my question. I just think the rule is not clear, in other words, what is "in all other respects the argument can be converted to the type of the implicit object parameter"? while the argument is a rvalue of type `volatile A` and the parameter type is `volatile const A&`? how to convert them? or after certain transformations and as long as the result can convert to the target type?

Comment: Or does that particular rule means that as long as their type are reference-compatible? then such a binding would be permitted?

Comment: @jackX Imho, it's quite clear that [over.match.funcs ]/5.1 removes the _prohibation_ of [dcl.init.ref]/5 regarding rvalues, such that the argument type being an rvalue is no longer relevant; the exception already says that an rvalue, in this case, can bind to lvalue (beyond the usual rules). I interpret _"in all **other** a respects"_, as I've also written in my answer, that the argument type without any ref-qualifiers (`volatile A`) can be converted to the implicit object parameter" (`const volatileA&`).

Comment: @jackX However, I will not spend any more time on this question, though, as you seem to (from past experience) swiftly downvote answers that do not agree with your own interpretation of the standard. My answer shows, by standardese, what the implicit object parameter is (which is one of the questions in your multi-question question). If you think the standard is unclear on this, I don't think StackOverflow is the ideal forum (as you have seen before), but rather submitting an ...

Comment: ... editorial issue to [github.com/cplusplus/draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). It seems many of your questions thus far focuses on passages that possible have an editorial issue ("we know how it works, but it could be more clear"). E.g. as I point out above, it could arguably also be explicitly pointed out that [dcl.init.ref]/5 is entirely waved (also the remand for non-volatile, not just constness) by the special rule of [over.match.funcs ]/5.1.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  From your comments, I think that the rule states about that: "in all other a respects" means as long as their types are reference-compatible, then such bind would be permitted.

Comment: @jackX Yes I agree that would be the more formal description; my answer updated accordingly. Again, if you believe the spec to be unclear, specifically w.r.t. unclarities that can be addressed by means of editorial changes, I encourage your to attempt posting an issue to [github.com/cplusplus/draft](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft). Imo the "in all other respects" here is not that unclear, but arguably [over.match.funcs ]/5.1 should also explicitly mentioned the waiving of when the implicit object parameter is `volatile` (currently only implied; waiving of `const` is described explicitly).

Comment: That doesn't work. I have posted issues on github more than once. The response is that's not a editorial issue instead may be `CWG`, hence that can't be processed in their responsbility. Actually, that rule intend to state that, in general, only a lvalue reference is top-level const-qualified but is not volatile-qualified can it be bound to a reference-compatible rvalue. However, it definitely doesn't mean that we can waive cv-qualifier in any case when the postfix-expression is a rvalue. e.g https://godbolt.org/z/fPqeox...

Comment: After all, replace "in all other respects..." to "reference-compatible" is more precise(IMHO) and easy to understand what the intent of that rule. So, reword that rule to "even if the implicit object parameter is of lvalue reference type, it can also bind to an rvalue as long as their types are reference-compatible".

Comment: _" it definitely doesn't mean that we can waive cv-qualifier in any case when the postfix-expression is a rvalue."_ - I fully agree, the waiving is only for the limitation of when rvalues may usually bind to lvalue references (but we still need to respect other rules w.r.t. cv-qualifiers, as per reference-compatibility requirements). _"is more precise(IMHO) and easy to understand what the intent of that rule"_ - yep, I agree, emphasis mostly on the "more precise"; your suggested re-wording would also cover the waiving of the volatile case (for prohibiting binding), which is only implied atm.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you are not getting feedback on your editorial issues at github. Is it the same if you also provide a commit proposing how to update the text? Possible (as the draft editors are very well-experienced in how the standard text is updated) some of the issues you have found are actually beyond editorial, in which case I guess CWG is the way to go (I don't know how, though). Do you happen to have a more local (say, national) representation for the ISO C++ Committee where you live? If so, maybe you could get involved through that group.

Comment: That's an unfortunately thing. In my country, there's no representation for the ISO C++ Committee. Sometimes, I use [std-discussion](https://lists.isocpp.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/std-discussion) to talk about my opinions for potential defectives in the standard.